# Can't get dictionary to save to .txt file without syntax error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I add to my dictionary 2 different meals and 2 different unit amounts, which then saves to my text file perfectly fine, but then when I exit the program and reload the file, I get a syntax error. (Also some functions look like they are not completed but that's just because Stack Overflow told me not to add all the code in.

Tried making the dictionary not start as an empty dictionary but that didn't solve anything.

```
import pprint
import time

pretty = pprint.PrettyPrinter(width = 20)
meals = {}
command = ""
condition = False

f = open("meals.txt", "r+")
f.write(str(meals))
f.close()

def save_dict_to_file(meals):
    f = open("meals.txt", "r+")
    f.write(str(meals))
    f.close()

def load_dict_from_file():
    f = open("meals.txt", "r+")
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    return eval(data)

load_dict_from_file()

def add_entry():
    meal = input("Enter name of meal: ").lower()
    units = int(input("Enter units needed: "))
    meals[meal] = units
    pretty.pprint(meals)
    save_dict_to_file(meals)

def remove_entry():

def help():

def view_dict():

def ending_message():

while True:
    command = input("> ").lower()
    if command == "help":
    help()
    elif command == "add":
        add_entry()
    elif command == "exit":
        save_dict_to_file(meals)
        ending_message()
        time.sleep(3)
        break
    elif command == "remove":
        remove_entry()
    elif command == "view":
        view_dict()
```

After adding multiple entries to the dictionary, I'm expecting to be able to quit the program, load back up and when I type view to look at my entries, see what I have previously added in.This is what I get -

```
PS C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Python\own_projects\mosh> python diabetes.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "diabetes.py", line 24, in <module>
        load_dict_from_file()
      File "diabetes.py", line 22, in load_dict_from_file
        return eval(data)
      File "<string>", line 1
        {}lasagne': 12, 'fish and chips': 16}
                ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You should use `pickle` instead of eval'ing a text file.  It's safer and the standard way to save python objects to files.  Alternatively, you could also use the `json` library since you're just saving dictionaries.

Comment: `pickle` is not safer than `eval`, the attack vector is just less trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't entirely remember how pretty print works, but this way of accomplishing this is very fragile. The likelihood of something not printing in a way you expect it to is pretty high, which could break things as it is now.

I recommend using a more standard data transmission format like CSV or JSON. If your data is flat, I recommend CSV. If your data is more complex, I recommend JSON.

I'll edit this answer momentarily with examples of both methods.

CSV example:

```
import csv

# This is a list of dictionaries
data = [
    {
        'meal': 'breakfast',
        'units': 20
    },
    {
        'meal': 'lunch',
        'units': 40
    },
    {
        'meal': 'dinner',
        'units': 50
    }
]
# If you wanted the values for lunch, you could do data[1]['units']
# This says access the second value inside the data list,
# and get the value for the units in that dictionary

def write_data(file_path='meals.csv'):
    # Open the file for writing without adding extra new lines
    # The with syntax will automatically close it for us
    with open(file_path, 'w', newline='') as f:
        # Create a dictionary writer, telling it what columns to expect
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ['meal', 'units'])
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(data)

def read_data(file_path='meals.csv'):
    new_data = []
    # open the file for reading
    with open(file_path) as f:
        # Create a dictionary reader. It will figure things out automagically
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
            new_data.append(row)
    return new_data

print('writing data...')
write_data()

print('reading data...')
print(read_data())
```

JSON example:

```
import json

data = {
    'lunch': 10,
    'breakfast': 20,
    'dinner': 30
}

def write_data(file_path='meals.json'):
    # Open the file for writing without adding extra new lines
    # The with syntax will automatically close it for us
    with open(file_path, 'w', newline='') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)

def read_data(file_path='meals.json'):
    # open the file for reading
    with open(file_path) as f:
        new_data = json.load(f)
    return new_data

print('writing data...')
write_data()

print('reading data...')
print(read_data())
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I have implemented it but I'm having a new issue, It all works fine when adding entries, when i load the program up again and view the entries it shows up perfect, but if i then add  another entry it resets the dictionary.

Comment: @lammyalex Are you reading the file when your program starts? Your CSV/JSON file is acting as your persistent storage. When your program starts, it has no information. It needs to retrieve the old information from the file before adding new information.

The workflow should look like this:
Use read_data() to get data from the file and store the output in a variable => make your adjustments => write the data back to the file with write_data. Also, please mark whichever answer you chose to go with as the answer to your question :)

Comment: yes I read the data, then make changes then write the data, but when i write the data it erases what was in it and replaces it with just the new entry i have added, if that makes sense. And I have marked it now thank you :)

Comment: @lammyalex Sorry for delay. Went to sleep. Huh, that's odd. Can I see how you're storing the data and how you're adding the entry? From your original post, it looks like you read the data into a variable `data`, but you add new data to a variable called `meals`. Is this happening in your current code, too? You'll need to add data to the same variable you read the data into. Something like this: https://gist.github.com/TheBeege/1d9a158dd04f590f30f0b243f7fbd027

Comment: No problem thanks for the help, I thought  I was doing it in the right order. Here is the full code for the program - https://github.com/lammyalex/Meal-Doseage-Planner/commit/dd4a318069769da416a61c225f1e2590e15ae0ad

Comment: I think the repository is private. The link doesn't work, and I don't see any repositories listed on your profile. You'll need to either make the repository public or add me as a collaborator. My username is the same on Github as here

Comment: Just added you onto it now. Thanks

Comment: Not sure how familiar you are with Github, but I submitted a pull request.

Comment: That's great thank you, really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably caused by not adding newlines to your file. A simple fix would be: `f.write(str(meals) + "\n")`

But writing code in a textfile and then evaluating it is a bad idea:

- The file will only ever be readable by your python program
- It is prone to syntax errors (as in your question)
- It is very unsafe. Malicious code could end up in your file.

As long as you only store text, numbers and true/false in your dictionary, it can be represented very cleanly by a JSON file. JSON has the advantage that it can be read by basically any programming language:

```
import json

data = {
    "A": 1,
    "B": {"C": 2}
}

# write data to file
with open("file.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(data))

# read data from file
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

If you store more complex objects in your file, maybe instances of classes etc, then you should look at pickle. That's another built-in library and a very convenient way to store almost everything from your python program. As Klaus D. has pointed out in a comment, pickle is not safer than your approach. You should never load a pickle object from an origin that you don't trust.

```
import pickle

with open("file.txt", "wb") as file:
    pickle.dump(data, file)

with open("file.txt", "rb") as file:
    data = pickle.load(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

this need to work:

```
import pprint
import time
import os
pretty = pprint.PrettyPrinter(width = 20)
meals = {}
command = ""
condition = False
n = False
if not os.path.isfile('meals.txt'):
    f = open("meals.txt", "w+")
    f.write(str(meals))
    f.close()
else:
    n = True

def save_dict_to_file(meals):
    f = open("meals.txt", "w+")
    f.write(str(meals))
    f.close()

def load_dict_from_file():
    f = open("meals.txt", "r+")
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    return eval(data)
if n:
    meals = load_dict_from_file()

def add_entry():
    meal = input("Enter name of meal: ").lower()
    units = int(input("Enter units needed: "))
    meals[meal] = units
    pretty.pprint(meals)
    save_dict_to_file(meals)
import os
def remove_entry():
    os.remove('meals.txt')

def help():
    pretty.pprint('help')

def view_dict():
    pretty.pprint(load_dict_from_file())

def ending_message():
    pretty.pprint('done')

while True:
    command = input("> ").lower()
    if command == "help":
        help()
    elif command == "add":
        add_entry()
    elif command == "exit":
        save_dict_to_file(meals)
        ending_message()
        time.sleep(3)
        break
    elif command == "remove":
        remove_entry()
    elif command == "view":
        view_dict()
```